# Dual boot "stealth" mode?

Tags: boot, grub2, dual-boot

Whenever I've installed Linux on a Windows laptop as dual-boot, i.e. where upon boot the user is prompted with which OS to boot, there's always a boot menu, where you can choose between Windows, Linux, Safe Mode, etc.

Is there a way to install Grub, or a setting in Grub, or some other boot loader, that removes the menu, so that the presence of Linux on the machine isn't detectable (unless of course one begins to look into why a lot of hard disk space seems to be missing...)

Booting the desired OS would then be accomplished by holding a button or - better yet - a USB key in a slot (perhaps even with a specific RSA key on it)?

Comment: `GRUB_TIMEOUT_STYLE=hidden` in `/etc/default/grub` may be a partial solution for you - [see docs](https://www.gnu.org/software/grub/manual/grub/html_node/Simple-configuration.html)

Answer (score 2):

Yes, there is.

The simplest way would be to set `GRUB_TIMEOUT_STYLE=hidden` in `/etc/default/grub` (or for older GRUB versions, `GRUB_HIDDEN_TIMEOUT=<number of seconds>`, `GRUB_HIDDEN_TIMEOUT_QUIET=true` and `GRUB_TIMEOUT=0` which is an older, now-deprecated way to set the same thing).

This will display nothing at all unless <kbd>Esc</kbd> or <kbd>F4</kbd> are pressed, or <kbd>Shift</kbd> is held down while GRUB is waiting for the timeout to expire.

If you are planning to use a USB key, how about moving both GRUB and the `/boot` of your installation to the USB key? The GRUB on the USB key would load the kernel and initramfs from the USB, and within the USB there could be a key file to unlock the `cryptsetup` disk encryption on the laptop's hard disk partition reserved for Linux use (whose partition type could be anything, e.g. imitating a vendor's recovery partition).

If you use `cryptsetup` in regular LUKS mode, the encrypted partition will be easy to identify as a LUKS encrypted volume, but if you use a detached LUKS header or e.g. the `tcrypt` mode of `cryptsetup` (= TrueCrypt/VeraCrypt compatible mode) the encrypted partition will be practically indistinguishable from a partition overwritten with random data unless you know the correct unlocking key/passphrase. These options might work well together with the GRUB-and-`/boot`-on-USB scheme.